# How to export NPM module to use it without package name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I'm trying to export a NPM module to use it without package name.

This is the usual way to export module:

```
function hello(){
    console.log("hello");
}

module.exports.hello = hello;
```

And we use this like that:

```
const h = require("hello");

h.hello();
```

But I want to use it without h variable. So I want to use this module like that:

```
require("hello");

hello();
```

How can I export this module like it?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, just expose your function on the global scope of your environment, this is `window` for the browser or `global` for node. If you're using a bundler like webpack, you can just use `global`, webpack will do the rest.

```js
// hello.js

function hello() {
    console.log("hello");
}

window.hello = hello;

module.exports = hello;
```

```
// main.js

require("./hello");

hello(); // the same as `window.hello();`
```